# After signup action

Tags: users, modules

I'm trying to add an action after user signup so that we can post the clients external system so we can retrieve a customer number that we require. My question is does
EVENT_BEFORE_VERIFY_EMAIL run as soon as the user signs up or is their another method of achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `EVENT_AFTER_SAVE` event to handle this, if you don't need the external call to be made before the user has verified their email.

Something like this:

```
Event::on(
    User::class,
    User::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
    function(ModelEvent $event) {
        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $event->sender;

        // If this is a new user
        if ($event->isNew) {
            // Call external system here
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you that's exactly what I was looking for since account verification won't be needed for the store but we still need to create a new customer on their internal system.